# How to calculate average time between different events from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I am currently trying to calculate the average processing time of a messages in PostGres, there are multiple stages in the processing lifecycle and I would like to identify the average processing time between each stage. I have successfully calculated the average processing time for the full lifecycle using the following:

```
select AVG(e2.timestamp - e.timestamp) avg_gap
from event e
join event e2 on (e.message_id = e2.message_id)
where e.event_stage= 'start' and e.timestamp > '2022-10-01T00:00:08.000001Z' and e.timestamp < '2022-10-31T23:59:59.999999Z'
and e2.event_stage= 'end' and e2.timestamp > '2022-10-01T00:00:08.000001Z' and e2.timestamp < '2022-10-31T23:59:59.999999Z'
```

However I would now like to add additional event stages to the query to calculate the average processing time between each stage of the lifecycle.

As I am an SQL noob I have tried to update my query to the below; but receive the error operator does not exist: interval & interval.

```
select AVG((e3.timestamp - e2.timestamp) & (e2.timestamp - e.timestamp)) avg_gap
from event e
join event e2 on (e.message_id = e2.message_id)
join event e3 on (e2.message_id = e3.message_id)
where e.event_stage= 'start' and e.timestamp > '2022-10-01T00:00:08.000001Z' and e.timestamp < '2022-10-31T23:59:59.999999Z'
and e2.event_stage= 'validation' and e2.timestamp > '2022-10-01T00:00:08.000001Z' and e2.timestamp < '2022-10-31T23:59:59.999999Z'
and e3.event_stage= 'end' and e3.timestamp > '2022-10-01T00:00:08.000001Z' and e3.timestamp < '2022-10-31T23:59:59.999999Z'
```

I was hoping that the above would provide me with an average processing time from start to validation, and validation to end.

NOTE - There are other stages that I would eventually like to include such as parsing and transforming.

Is it possible for someone to provide some input on how to add multiple stages to the query?

EDIT - table structure as per the below:

[image: Table structure]

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: RF1991 thanks, postgresql tag added

Comment: Looking at the queries, it seems the important columns you have in the table are "message_id, stage and timestamp"
Do you also happen to have some kind of an "stage_id"? That would help if you wanted to use lag/lead to calculate the timestamp differences

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify the table structure?
Along with stage_event, do you also have some kind of an ID associated to this stage?
That would help if you wanted to use lead/lag to get the timestamp for the "next stage"
Something like this -

```
SELECT message, 
stage_name,
timestamp,
lag(timestamp, 1) over (partition by message_id order by event_stage_id) as next_stage_timestamp
FROM events
```

You could then use "next_stage_timestamp - timestamp" to get your difference and average it grouping by event_stage.

Like this -

```
select stageName, 
avg(next_stage_timestamp - timestamp) as avg_time
from above_results
group by stageName
```

This is better than doing multiple self joins. However it would work only if you had some kind of an ID associated to the stage_event.
So your table would be like this -

```
Message     StageID     StageName   Timestamp
----------------------------------------------
A               1       Start           00
A               2       Calculate       20
A               3       Intermediate    30
A               4       Validate        40
A               5       End             60
```

Comment: The table structure is as follows; the stage_id is unique to each message_id and stage, and therefore not consistent across different message IDs

Comment: table structure added to question

Comment: Then my answer should work..as long as the stage IDs don't go backwards for a give message. Like 202 for START and 201 for END

Comment: Thanks Manu - I should have added that the stage IDs are actually UUIDs, I also want to calculate the average across all messages rather than see the processing time for each individual message.

Comment: Added the query to calculate avg time per stage across all messages. Maybe use the 1st SQL as a subquery.